# What is the time complexity of a Turing Machine that iterates through each prime number from 2 to K (assume oracle generates the next prime)?

Tags: time-complexity

Let `NextPrimeNumber` be an oracle that accepts a prime number `n` and returns the smallest prime number `m` such that `m > n`. It can be called by a Turing machine and returns the answer in constant time.

Let `F` be the Turing Machine that receives `K` a positive integer as a number. Suppose its code is the following:

```
current_prime = 2
while (current_prime <= K):
  current_prime = NextPrimeNumber(current_prime)
```

**What is the time complexity of `F`?**

If we printed out all numbers from `2` to `K` then it would take exponential time in terms of the bit length `k` of `K`. However we only iterate only over the primes, not all numbers from `2` to `K`. I believe primes represent `1/ln(K)` of primes less than or equal to `K`. Therefore the time complexity would be: `(2^k)/ln(K)` - which would still be exponential or at least super-polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The running time is $O(K/\ln K)$.  This is an exponential running time: the input takes $\lg K$ bits (assuming $K$ is specified in binary), so the running time is exponential in the length of the input.  If you set $k=\lg K$, then the running time is $O(2^k/k)$, which is an exponential function of $k$.